# GitHub Actions - how to connect to an external MySql database

Tags: mysql, github, action

I'm building an application in Python and using GitHub Actions to automate the testing 'on push'. However, I now want to connect my app to an existing MySql database.
From searching the Marketplace, Google and YouTube, I can see the following options:

1. use the MySql supplied with the GitHub Actions' Ubuntu virtual environment
2. setup a new MySql dB inside the GitHub Actions VM.
3. Setup MySql inside a Docker container and connect to it from another Docker container containing my app.
   What I can't see is how to connect out of the GitHub Actions VM to an existing database on my network. Is it possible and should I expect to see a pre-built action to do this in the Marketplace.
   Sorry for such an obtuse question: old, out-of-date programmer new to both CI/CD and containerisation. Thank you.

Comment: Why is the database in your environment special? As a test couldn't the sample data be created in the GH infrastructure? [services](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers) are the obvious way if you take a step back from obtusely insisting on a solution. To do it external there's [github hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners).

Comment: I'm not being obtuse - I've been open about being new to CI/CD. As a longstanding back-end programmer, I'm just surprised to not find an Action in the GH marketplace for people wanting to test against their production / pre-production standard (hardware-wise) databases, perhaps less important for unit testing but fundamental in integration testing where latency matters. I will export the data into a container for now. Thanks for the suggestion about GH hosted runners.

Comment: Ack, maybe [staging deployments](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/deployments/deployments).